Upload photo and save it to DB with Filament Laravel
I am using Laravel, with the Filament library. I uploaded images, they are saved in the corresponding storage folder, but when saving the data in the table, data is only saved when uploading the images from the edit screen and not from the create screen. In both cases the image is stored in the local folder, but the impact on the DB only occurs when editing an already generated element.
I share the codes: Venueresource.php
 <?php

namespace App\Filament\Resources;

use App\Filament\Resources\VenueResource\Pages;
use App\Filament\Resources\VenueResource\RelationManagers;
use App\Models\Venue;
use Filament\Forms;
use Filament\Forms\Form;
use Filament\Resources\Resource;
use Filament\Tables;
use Filament\Tables\Table;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope;
use Filament\Tables\Columns\ImageColumn;
use Cheesegrits\FilamentGoogleMaps\Fields\Map;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Hidden;
 

class VenueResource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = Venue::class;
    

    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-rectangle-stack';

    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('name')
                ->required()
                ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('address')
                ->label('Address:')
                ->required()
                ->extraAttributes(['id' => 'autocomplete']),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('zip')
                ->required()
                ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('city')
                ->required()
                ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('state')
                ->required()
                ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('country')
                ->required()
                ->maxLength(255),
                
                Hidden::make('lt')
                ->required(),
                
                Hidden::make('lg')
                ->required(),

                Map::make('location')
                ->mapControls([
                    'mapTypeControl'    => false,
                    'scaleControl'      => true,
                    'streetViewControl' => false,
                    'rotateControl'     => false,
                    'fullscreenControl' => true,
                    'searchBoxControl'  => false, 
                    'zoomControl'       => true,
                ])
                ->reactive()
                ->afterStateUpdated(function ($state, callable $get, callable $set) {
                    $set('lt', $state['lat']);
                    $set('lg', $state['lng']);
                })
                ->autocomplete(
                    fieldName: 'address',
                    placeField: 'name',
                )
                ->defaultLocation([39.526610, -107.727261])
                ->autocompleteReverse(true) 
                ->reverseGeocode([
                    'city' => '%L',
                    'state' => '%A1',
                    'country'=> '%c',
                    'zip' => '%z',
                ]),

                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('region')
                ->required()
                ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('socials')
                ->required()
                ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('website')
                ->required()
                ->maxLength(255),

                Forms\Components\FileUpload::make('photos')
                ->label('Photosssss')
                ->disk('public')
                ->multiple() 
                ->image() 
                ->directory('venue_photos')
                ->required(),

                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('description')
                    ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\Select::make('created_by')
                    ->label('Created By')
                    ->required()
                    ->relationship('createdBy', 'name') // relationship to the User model
                    ->searchable() // alows searching
                    ->placeholder('Select a user'),
            ]);
    }

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('name')
                    ->searchable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('address')
                    ->searchable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('description')
                    ->searchable()
                    ->formatStateUsing(function ($state) {
                        return \Str::limit($state, 35, '...'); // Limit a string to a maximum of  10 characters
                    }),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('createdBy.name')
                    ->label('Created By')
                    ->numeric()
                    ->sortable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('region')
                ->searchable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('socials')
                ->url(fn ($record) => $record->socials, shouldOpenInNewTab: true)
                    ->sortable(),
                
                Tables\Columns\ImageColumn::make('photos.photo_url')
                ->stacked()
                ->limit(3)
                ->limitedRemainingText(isSeparate: true),
                
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('website')
                ->url(fn ($record) => $record->socials, shouldOpenInNewTab: true)
                    ->sortable(),
                        
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('created_at')
                    ->dateTime()
                    ->sortable()
                    ->toggleable(isToggledHiddenByDefault: true),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('updated_at')
                    ->dateTime()
                    ->sortable()
                    ->toggleable(isToggledHiddenByDefault: true),
            ])
            ->filters([
                //
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\ViewAction::make(),
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ]);
    }

    public static function getRelations(): array
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'index' => Pages\ListVenues::route('/'),
            'create' => Pages\CreateVenue::route('/create'),
            'view' => Pages\ViewVenue::route('/{record}'),
            'edit' => Pages\EditVenue::route('/{record}/edit'),
        ];
    }
}

CreateVenue.php:
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Resources\VenueResource\Pages;

use App\Filament\Resources\VenueResource;
use Filament\Actions;
use Filament\Resources\Pages\CreateRecord;
use App\Models\VenuePhoto;

class CreateVenue extends CreateRecord
{
    protected static string $resource = VenueResource::class;

    protected function afterSave(): void
    {
        // Obtener el array de fotos subidas
        $uploadedPhotos = $this->data['photos'];
        dd($this->data['photos']);
        // Guardar las URLs en la tabla venue_photos
        foreach ($uploadedPhotos as $photo) {
            VenuePhoto::create([
                'venue_id' => $this->record->id, // ID del venue actual
                'photo_url' => $photo, // URL de la imagen
            ]);
        }
    }
}

Editvenue.php:
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Resources\VenueResource\Pages;

use App\Filament\Resources\VenueResource;
use Filament\Actions;
use Filament\Resources\Pages\EditRecord;
use App\Models\VenuePhoto;

class EditVenue extends EditRecord
{
    protected static string $resource = VenueResource::class;

    protected function getHeaderActions(): array
    {
        return [
            Actions\ViewAction::make(),
            Actions\DeleteAction::make(),
        ];
    }

    protected function afterSave(): void
    {
        // Obtener el array de fotos subidas
        $uploadedPhotos = $this->data['photos'];
        
        // Guardar las URLs en la tabla venue_photos
        foreach ($uploadedPhotos as $photo) {
            VenuePhoto::create([
                'venue_id' => $this->record->id, // ID del venue actual
                'photo_url' => $photo, // URL de la imagen
            ]);
        }
    }
}

Venue.php (model)
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Venue extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'venues';

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'address',
        'zip',
        'city',
        'state',
        'country',
        'lt',
        'lg',
        'description',
        'created_by',
        'socials',
        'website',
        'region'
    ];

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(VenuePhoto::class, 'venue_id');
    }

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Event::class, 'venue_id');
    }

    public function createdBy()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_by');
    }
    
    protected $casts = [
        'photos' => 'array',
    ];

}

What is the problem? The dd does not run, Why don't you enter to execute this part of the code?. Why does Editvenue.php: work and CreateVenue.php: not?
